# Java 8 Stream with map and multiples sets

Tags: java, foreach, hashmap, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to write these lines using java8 streams:

```
    for (Town town : getAllTowns(routes)) {

        if (originTown.equals(town))
            continue;

        for (Route route : routes) {
            if (route.hasOrigin(originTown) && route.hasDestine(town)) {
                distances.put(town, route.getDistance());
                break;
            }
            distances.put(town, maxDistance);
        }
    }
    return distances; //Map<Town,Integer>
```

The result that I got so far is:

```
Map<Town, Integer> distances = getAllTowns(routes).stream()
.filter(town -> !originTown.equals(town))
.forEach(town -> routes.stream()
        .filter(route -> route.hasOrigin(originTown) && route.hasDestine(town)
        ...)
return distances;
```

How can I collect after the inner filter and build the Map< Town,Integer> where the integer is the route.getDistance()?
I tried to use:

```
.collect(Collectors.toMap(route -> route.getDestineTown(), route -> route.getDistance()))
```

But it is inside the forEach call, then I can't return it to my variable `distances` because it generates the map only for the inner call. I did not understand it. Any input would be really helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `findFirst()` to build a list that contains, for each town, the first route that has that town as the destination, and then call `toMap()` on it. The default values for missing cities can be handled separately.

```
Collection<Town> towns = getAllTowns(routes);
Map<Town, Integer> distances = towns.stream()
    .filter(town -> !originTown.equals(town))
    .map(town -> routes.stream()
        .filter(route -> route.hasOrigin(originTown) && route.hasDestine(town))
        .findFirst())
    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
    .collect(toMap(route -> route.get().getDestine(), route -> route.get().getDistance()));
towns.stream()
    .filter(town -> !distances.containsKey(town))
    .forEach(town -> distances.put(town, maxDistance));
```

(Note that `town` is no longer available in `collect()`, but you can take advantage of the fact that each route got added only if its destination town was `town`.)

Also note that `toMap()` doesn't accept duplicate keys. If there can be multiple routes to any town (which I assume there might be), you should use `groupingBy()` instead.

Comment: Hey, so, the `toMap()` is fine because the Town is identified by its name and I don't really want duplicate keys. It worked fine. Thanks. One more thing is: What would be a nice way to include the `distances.put(town, maxDistance);` for all towns that do not satisfies the second filter. Because after the filter I wont have the town object available anymore. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why are you filtering them in the first place if you want all of the entries to be in the map? (I probably don't understand what you're trying to achieve; please clarify.)

Comment: In the second `for` loop there is the if statement which checks the origin and  destine. When it is not satisfied, puts in the `distances` map the `maxDistance` for that town. Using the `filter` on routes stream, works fine for the case where we have a match for the origin and destine. But I was wondering if it does not have a match, how would I perform the `"else"` operation in the stream.

Comment: @felipe.forbeck: Gah, I didn't see that line. That'll be trickier; I think the most clear solution might be to do it on two steps; see my updated answer.

Comment: Awesome! That worked. Just need to use this for the `collect` call: `.collect(Collectors.toMap(route -> route.isPresent() ? route.get().getDestineTown() : null,
      route -> route.isPresent() ? route.get().getDistance() : 0));`

Comment: @felipe.forbeck: Great! But you find that `collect()` rewrite to be necessary, I think you left out `.filter(Optional::isPresent)`.

Comment: Actually I am using the `.filter(Optional::isPresent)` then when I use the `collect` call it just receives an `Optional route`. Even if I remove the `filter` call it returns the `Optional route`. I believe it happens because the `findFirstResult` call, which returns an `Optional` object.

Comment: @felipe.forbeck: Whoops - my bad. The collect call does need to use `get()`, but you don't need the ternary conditionals as long as you keep the filter: `.collect(toMap(route -> route.get().getDestine(), route -> route.get().getDistance()))`

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two options to solve this. Either you create your resulting `Map` beforehand and use nested `foreach`s:

```
Map<Town, Integer> distances = new HashMap<>();
    getAllTowns(routes).stream().filter(town -> !originTown.equals(town))
            .forEach(town -> routes.stream().forEach(route -> distances.put(town,
                    route.hasOrigin(originTown) && route.hasDestine(town) ? route.getDistance() : maxDistance)));
```

The other option is to `collect` your stream to a `Map` by creating an intermediate `Object` which is essentially a Pair of `Town` and `Integer`:

```
Map<Town, Integer> distances = getAllTowns(routes).stream().filter(town -> !originTown.equals(town))
            .flatMap(town -> routes.stream()
                    .map(route -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Town, Integer>(town,
                            route.hasOrigin(originTown) && route.hasDestine(town) ? route.getDistance()
                                    : maxDistance)))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry.getKey(), entry -> entry.getValue()));
```